# How to blur image edges using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a Javascript solution that allows blurring edges of images. I can't use a mask as I need a pixelated kind of blur. Please see the image below.

[image]

Comment: possibly you could try this http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/08/image-blur-using-jquery-and-css.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pixastic has a blur function available:

http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/blur/

You could replicate your edge-blur by cloning the image on top of itself, cropping the front one and blurring the back one.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use edge library 
http://www.netzgesta.de/edge/